# jQuery AJAX Posting values to another page in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post values to another page in jquery ajax and php

This is my **form** in page1.php.

```
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
     Name : <input type="text" id="N_Txt">
     Email : <input type="text" id="Email_Txt">
     <input type="button" id="Sub_Btn" value="button">
</form>
```

This is my AJAX in **page1.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Sub_Btn').click(function() {
         var nm = $('#N_Txt').val();
         var email = $('#Email_Txt').val(); 
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"page2.php",
             data:{ nm : nm , email : email },
             success:function(resp){
                console.log('success ajax');
             },
             error:function(resp){
                console.log('error ajax');
             }
         });
     });
});
```

This is my **page2.php**

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['nm'];
   echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Control is not even going to page2.php. How do i do it? I dont want to send values through query string window.location. 
Thanks

Comment: How do you say that value is not posted

Comment: Why putting the `action="page1.php"` in the form ? Could be misleading.

Comment: What do you get in the console?

Comment: @Life Hacker i do not know whether values are posting or not. bcoz control isnt going to page 2.

Comment: @Jb Drucker i have writeen my form in page 1. does it not make sense?

Comment: Your ajax is pointing to page1 so , url:"page1.php" should be there.You have set form action to page1.php and your ajax goes to page2.php .This is wrong code.improve it please

Comment: @Alex i am getting error ajax.

Comment: @Pratik Joshi. If i mention url:"page1.php" , then how do i echo values in page2.php. I mean i wanted to echo those values in page2.php

Comment: Your code is properly workng in my pc localhost.I get ajax response  whatever i post in page 1

Comment: check  http://postimg.org/image/ya61r0zax/  .And http://postimg.org/image/449c4aigj/

Comment: how do it echo those values in page2.php

Comment: @user3778091 , sir this is ajax , You get response from page 2 IN page 1 itself .You return values from page2.php instead actually going there.You just reload small part of page using ajax.Anyway when u use ajax you are not going to page2.php Directly. then why u want to ?

Comment: @user3778091 , sir Are you new in php ,ajax? spend some time on php.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put action="page2.php"
And your form in page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
     Name : <input type="text" id="N_Txt">
     Email : <input type="text" id="Email_Txt">
     <input type="button" id="Sub_Btn" value="button">
 </form>
```

And in your page2.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Thats it. You dont need a AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You get a response and did you look into that

alert the response or you can check like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#Sub_Btn').click(function() {
             var nm = $('#N_Txt').val();
             var email = $('#Email_Txt').val(); 
             $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"page2.php",
                 data:{ nm : nm , email : email },
                 success:function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                 },
                 error:function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                 }
             });
         });
    });
```

Comment: but i would like to echo my values in page2.php. which is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you like to echo your values in page2.php don't make an AJAX call. Just set `action="page2.php"` and forget your AJAX.

And on page2.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Seriously, this was this simple ? :D What a bad-asked question, I thought AJAX was mandatory for you.